# mixing simple colors in CSS

Tags: css, svg, less

i have several SVGs which change of fill color depending on some parameters. When two parameters are on the same SVG feature, then I would like to mix the two corresponding colors so that user can get an idea that in this SVG there are these 2 different 'things'.

For example, which is the resulting color to be applying after mixing BlueViolet (8A2BE2) and Aquamarine (7FFFD4). Is there some formula around in Javascript?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add each of the R/G/B components separately and divide by two, e.g.

```
(8A + 7F) / 2 = 84
(2B + FF) / 2 = 95
(E2 + D4) / 2 = DB

mixed color = #8495DB
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent jQuery plugin called [xcolor](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/) which is helpful when dealing with colors. What you are looking for is probably the [color mixing](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/#meth_combine) method.